# Create Grouped TableView without using TableViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview, tableview

I have a TableView that is inside a ViewController that is embedded into a Navigation Controller. I would like to make the TableView a grouped TableView. I have found countless ways to do this using a TableView Controller, but using a TableView with a Custom Cell / Dynamic Prototypes inside it doesn't seem to be giving me the same options in XIB.[image]

As you can see I don't have any options for how many sections I want the grouped TableView to have. (The answer is 2) When I set the Content to Static Cells it allows me to create 2 groups, but then Xcode complains telling me "Static table views are only valid when embedded in UITableViewController instances". I'm sure it's possible to have Dynamic Prototypes as the content and still have a grouped TableView, I just don't know where to find a starting point.

Comment: `Static table views are only valid when embedded in UITableViewController instances` it sounds like you have a `UIViewController` containing a table view and not the more specific `UITableViewController` subclass of `UIViewController`. Is there a reason you do not want to embed a `UITableViewController` in your navigation controller instead? If so, you're not going to be able to use static cells defined in your nib and will need to implement a `UITableViewDataSource` to return them instead.

Comment: Jonah, you should post your comment as an answer. That's it. The OP is asking about static  table views, and they only work inside a `UITableViewController`.

Comment: I wanted to achieve a group table view with 2 sections. Each section will have it's own data source,and will have to be dynamic cells, as the data source will change. Maybe I'm not asking the right questions for what I'm looking to do?