# How to create a grouped TableView without using a TableViewController

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift2

I have a UITableView and I would like it to have 2 sections. I now know that you can only have grouped sections if you're using a UITableViewController and if you're using static cells, neither of which I am. Is that I want to do possible? If so where can I turn for help on setting this up. It seems like every tutorial I have found is for the example of using a UITableViewController.

Comment: So you just added a UITableView to an UIViewController?

Comment: Yes, as I need the flexibly to add other things to the controller, that a UITableViewController doesn't provide

Comment: Did you think about just adding a second TableView below?

Comment: yes, but I just wanted to know all my options, or if that was the best way of going about this.

Comment: Ah ok, in that case i would add a ContainerView which contains a UITableViewController. Check this link: https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-access-UITableViewController-from-a-container-view-in-a-UIViewController

Comment: Your assumptions are wrong. You can have sections and grouped style w/o using a `UITableViewController` or static cells. You may still need a controller that is a `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource` for your `UITableView`.

Comment: If you're not satisfied with the lack of initial response, you could improve [your original question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35166864/create-grouped-tableview-without-using-tableviewcontroller) and/or offer a bounty.  But please don't dupe your own question.

Comment: Petah, I started another question as that question was answered saying it wasn't possible to do what I was asking. So I tried to ask a different question with a different problem. I thought that was proper protocol?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the tableView's [`style`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableView/style) property to `.Grouped` and return `2` from `numberOfSections...`-method should yield a good result. Where does this standard approach fail?

Comment: Thanks Jan I thought was  was trying to do was possible. That's the exact method I have been looking for!

Comment: Do you by chance have an example of somewhere I might be able to find a tutorial on this topic? As I have said before, I have only found examples of using a UITableViewController with grouped tables.